# LIKE and AND in the same query doesn't work out like it should

Tags: mysql

This is my query, it doesn't matter if approved is set to 0 or 1 it will give me all the rows anyway

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tutorials` 
WHERE tags LIKE '% php %' OR tags LIKE 'php %' OR tags LIKE '% php' OR tags = 'php' 
AND approved=1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try brackets

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tutorials` 
WHERE   (       tags LIKE '% php %' 
            OR  tags LIKE 'php %' 
            OR  tags LIKE '% php' 
            OR  tags = 'php' 
        )
AND approved=1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing some colons:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tutorials` 
WHERE (tags LIKE '% php %' OR tags LIKE 'php %' OR tags LIKE '% php' OR tags = 'php')
AND approved=1
```

The reason you should include colons, is because OR and AND operators are on the same level of precedence. When you omit the colons, your query would be parsed as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tutorials` 
WHERE (tags LIKE '% php %' OR (tags LIKE 'php %' OR (tags LIKE '% php' OR (tags = 'php' 
AND approved=1))))
```

Especially when using long lists of OR and AND operators in a query, it is advisable to use colons to make your intent clear. For a full list of the operator precedence in MySQL (which is generally common to other SQL dialects), see [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html).

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get what you exactly want. But this may be the one that you are looking for

> SELECT *  FROM `tutorials`  WHERE
>   **(** tags LIKE '% php %' OR tags LIKE 'php %' OR tags LIKE '% php' OR tags =
>   'php' **)** AND approved=1